# How to work with multiple CSS properties?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to work with CSS properties?

For instance:

```
-webkit-transform: scaleX(-1) scaleY(-1)
```

Can I easily remove *scaleX(-1)* or add something new, without rewriting the whole *-webkit-transform* or changing classes?

Comment: What are you asking here?  You can add/remove classes which reference the declarations that you want with jQuery quite easily.

Comment: @RyanP13 Suppose I need to change between 4 or even more different states and each of one has several properties for different browsers (-webkit-transform, filter, etc). I want to reduce the amount of code and find more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That css property takes two arguments. Therefore you cannot change one without touching the other. But this should be all you need to do:

```
$("#your-element").css("-webkit-transform","scaleX(-1) scaleY(-1)");
```

Edit

```
   function changeTransform(el, x,y){
     var val = x + " " + y;
     $(el).css({"-webkit-transform":val, "-moz-transform": val, "-webkit-transform": val, "-o-transform": val});
  }
```

Comment: Suppose I have `-moz-transform: scaleX(-1); -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1); -o-transform: scaleX(-1); -transform: scaleX(-1);` and I want to add `scaleY(-1)` and then maybe to remove `scaleX(-1)`, that means I'll have to write a class for every action and there is no way around?

Comment: You can define a function where you write set all these properties and then call it whenever you need with the new arguments.

Comment: So, it's impossible to work directly with arguments. I get it. I will consider using a function instead. Thanks.